# Maximizing Revenue

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A motion picture theater, which has an average daily attendance of $1,800 $ paid admissions, increased its admission price from \$$15.00$ to \$$15.50$. This resulted in a decrease of $100$ in daily paid admissions. Assuming that this pattern would continue—a decrease in daily admission for every \$$0.50$ increase in price of admission—find the price of a theater ticket that would result in the maximum receipts per day

What is the price of a theater ticket that would result in the maximum receipts per day?

Find the maximum profits per day?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: Are receipts/revenue the same?

Comment: Yes Narasimham it is

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shot at it.

Let's find the total attendance first with respect to the price. We know at $p = \$15$ we have $A(p) = 1800$. We see that $A(15.50) = 1700$. There's hopefully a linear relation, so let's figure out the line.

We have the slope will be

$$ \frac{A(15.50) - A(15)}{15.50-15} = \frac{-100}{0.5} = -200.$$

So our equation is something like

$$ A(p) = -200p + b.$$

We need to solve for $b$ now. Let's plug in the point $(15, 1800)$. We have

$$ A(15) = -200(15) + b = 1800.$$
We can solve for $b$ to get $b = 4800$. So the attendance at price point $p$ is going to be

$$A(p) = -200p + 4800.$$

Let's now figure out what the total revenue will be. This is going to be the price times the number of people who attend. So

$$R(p) = p\cdot A(p) = -200p^2 + 4800p.$$
This is a quadratic function with a negative leading coefficient, so we can use the vertex formula to find the price which will give us the maximum revenue. Recall the vertex formula is

$$ \left( - \frac{b}{2a}, R\left( -\frac{b}{2a}\right)\right).$$

Here $b = 4800$ and $a = -200$, so plug this in to get $-\frac{b}{2a} = 12$. So the maximum revenue occurs when the price is $\$12$ a ticket. Finally, the maximum revenue will be $R(12) = \$55200.$

**Edit** Ah, I reread your problem and realized you weren't asking for the maximum revenue, but rather the maximum number of receipts(?)

The maximum number of receipts are going to occur when you have the largest number of people attending. This is going to happen when $p =0$, and you'll have $4800$ people attending (at least if I'm understanding what you mean by receipts correctly). At least if we're being realistic about what the movie theater is going to (possibly) do. Otherwise this function is unbounded, so the movie theater could give away an insane amount of money. There are around 7.8 billion people in the world, so let's see how much the theater would have to give away in order to attract everybody in the world. We solve

$$ A(p) = -200p + 4800 =7,800,000,000.$$

This tells us $p = -38999976,$ or the theater is going to have to give away roughly \$39 million to each person in order to attract everybody in the world. This means the theater has \$304,199,812,800,000,000 or 304 quadrillion dollars.